# How to reset a mock invocation counter using Scalatra, Specs2, Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, specs2, scalatra

I never expected that I will need to ask a question on this site because everything is already answered normally but with Scalatra... I haven't find a lot of information so here it is:

I'm not experienced with all that so maybe I'm missing something but from what I understand, if I want to test the API that I develop on Scalatra, I need to start the server everytime I run the test suit, right ?

Second question, how can I reset the invocation counter on a method so I don't have to calculate how many times the method has been called since the beginning of the test suite ? Right now using this give me more than one because it counts the previous test.

```
there was one(*instance*).*method*(*parameter*)
```

I can still get around the problem by either counting or putting the test as first test for now but it's not a sustainable solution...

Other thing that I found:
Reset method on the mock... not found
http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#17

Isolating the test in a class scope:
We need to add

```
val servlet = new Servlet(eventRepoMock)
addServlet(servlet, "/*")
```

and we can't repeat the addServlet at every initialization 
https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.5/org.specs2.guide.Isolation.html

Last thing that I try is:

```
servlet.repo = mock[EventRepo]
```

but `repo` being a value, I can't change it like this.

Neither of these "solutions" feel very clean so I was wondering if someone had a genius idea that can solve that mess !?

Thank you in advance !

EDIT:
Thanks to Eric's comment the above question are solve(that was easy) but now I have problem because I'm testing the get/post which are asynchronous call so resetting the mock does not happen at the right time... Any suggestion ?

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
class EventServiceSpec extends ScalatraSpec with Mockito with Before { def is = s2"""
Event Service

GET an existing event
must return status 200                              $get_status200
must return the event with id = :id                 $get_rightEventElement
must call findById once on the event repository     $get_findByIdOnRepo
"""

lazy val anEvent = Event(1, "Some Event"
lazy val eventsBaseUrl = "/events"
lazy val existingEventUrl = s"$eventsBaseUrl/${anEvent.id}"

lazy val eventRepoMock = mock[EventRepository]

lazy val servlet = new Servlet(eventRepoMock)
addServlet(servlet, "/*")

def before = {
    eventRepoMock.findById(anEvent.id) returns Option(anEvent)
    eventRepoMock.findById(unexistingId) returns None
    eventRepoMock.save(anEvent) returns Option(anEvent)
}

def get_status200 = get(existingEventUrl){
    status must_== 200
}

def get_findByIdOnRepo = get(existingEventUrl){
    // TODO count considering previous test... need to find a cleaner way
    there was three(eventRepoMock).findById(anEvent.id)
}
```

Comment: So the `org.mockito.Mockito.reset` method on your mock repo didn't work?

Comment: Oh Yeah ! That works !

I feel a bit stupid now... I tried only `reset(eventRepoMock)` ... but... what is the difference with `org.mockito.Mockito.reset(eventRepoMock)` if I call it in a class that extends Mockito ?

Comment: I added a question to the original question post as well

Comment: Can you please post a full snipped (but simplified as much as possible)?

Comment: Can you also try to make your specification `sequential`? By default examples are executed concurrently and this might be why you see your tests failing.

Comment: `... def is = sequential ^ s2""" ...`

Comment: That's what I was looking for ! You are a my hero ! Thank you Eric :)

Comment: I added a more complete answer, also using the `BeforeAll` and `BeforeEach` traits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `org.mockito.Mockito` functions can still be used in a specs2 specification and `reset` is one of them.

Now, since you are sharing the state of a mock object across several examples, you not only need to reset the mock state before each example but you also need to make your specification `sequential`:

```
class EventServiceSpec extends ScalatraSpec with Mockito 
  with BeforeAll with BeforeEach { 
  def is = sequential ^ s2"""
  Event Service

  GET an existing event
    must return status 200                              $get_status200
    must return the event with id = :id                 $get_rightEventElement
    must call findById once on the event repository  $get_findByIdOnRepo
  """

  lazy val anEvent = Event(1, "Some Event")
  lazy val eventsBaseUrl = "/events"
  lazy val existingEventUrl = s"$eventsBaseUrl/${anEvent.id}"

  lazy val eventRepoMock = mock[EventRepository]

  lazy val servlet = new Servlet(eventRepoMock)

  def beforeAll = addServlet(servlet, "/*")

  def before = {
    reset(eventRepoMock)
    eventRepoMock.findById(anEvent.id) returns Option(anEvent)
    eventRepoMock.findById(unexistingId) returns None
    eventRepoMock.save(anEvent) returns Option(anEvent)
  }

  def get_status200 = get(existingEventUrl){
    status must_== 200
  }

  def get_findByIdOnRepo = get(existingEventUrl){
   there was one(eventRepoMock).findById(anEvent.id)
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you made it works with `BeforeEach` ? For me, I needed to use the deprecated `BeforeExample` instead because otherwise `before` was not called...

Comment: `BeforeExample` is defined as `trait BeforeExample extends BeforeEach
` so that should definitely work.

Comment: It should be simple, just changing the import and extends/with, right ? When I try it, the before method is just not called. Nothing in the logger and all the tests crash.
Nonetheless, I can live with the deprecated `BeforeExample` for now. I just wanted to mention it. If someone ever encounters the same problem than me, maybe I can spare him some time. Thanks again Eric !